# rails nested form still runs validations on destroyed fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a nested form in which the user can dynamically add and delete fields through javascript like in this rails cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=asciicast .

The user can click a link that will use javascript to destroy the field.  The only problem is I have a validation on the field that still gets triggered, since the way the rails cast sets up the javascript simply has the field still submit but with a parameter like this:

```
'_destroy' => true
```

so it is still validating it even though it will be destroyed.  How do I get the rails to skip validation on destroyed fields?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this?

```
validates :field, unless: :marked_for_destruction?
```